# html5 game with canvas, performance problems on firefox (4)

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, canvas

currently i work on a little js/canvas game called "tunnel 2" (i'm pretty sure there's a well known year old version of this, but i know of none). you can [try the game here](http://tapirpirates.net/tunnel2). also, i'd recommend chrome.

so, i developed in google chrome, and it works fine, even on my crappy old machine. i get around ~30 fps. on my coworkers notebook it yields >100fps. so far, so good. safari seems to work well too.

next i tried it on firefox 4 beta 10 ... and i only get ~10 fps. but surely ff4 isn't *that* slow, right?

i started to investigate. here's my main loop:

```
// starts the game loop
this.run = function () {
  this.draw();

  var
    t = this,
    timeLastTurn,
    timeThisTurn = (new Date()).getTime()-1;

  var loop = function () {
    timeLastTurn = timeThisTurn;
    timeThisTurn = (new Date()).getTime();

    // dt is the time difference between this turn and the last turn
    var dt = timeThisTurn - timeLastTurn;

    // player movement etc
    t.turn(dt);

    // draw game state
    var res = t.draw();

    // if there's no collision, game over
    if (!res.collision)
      t.setState(2);

    // actually, there's a browser dependent minimum timeout that
    // may vary. but even if it's more than 10ms - we don't care.
    // game should run at the same speed (though not as smooth)
    if (gameState == 1)
      timer = window.setTimeout(loop, 5);

    // just debug output
    debug = dt;
  }

  // start the main loop
  loop();
}
```

what i observed:

unsurprisingly, `this.draw();` is by far the most expensive function, but it takes only some milliseconds (around 5, actually), on chrome ... *and also on firefox*. nowhere near the >100ms it would take for meager 10fps! the whole `loop()` call takes not much more either, on firefox it takes less than 10ms!

the difference can be seen if you investigate `dt`. it should be around time-loop()-takes+5ms timeout (or whatever the browser minimum timeout value is).

but on ff4 the value is closer to 180ms, aka the next timeout event fires in 170ms instead of 5ms! if you play a little longer, it goes up to ~800ms for a single frame (gc, for sure), then it's back to 180ms.

does anybody have an idea what the culprit could be?

is the GC to blame? on the one hand i don't think i create too many short lived variables, and hey, 150ms every time!? but of course it could be. is there an easy way to check this? the chrome profiler logs gc times (around 0.10%), but the firebug profiler doesn't.

also interesting: the game runs faster (~5fps) with firebug enabled.

add. info: using setInterval instead of setTimeout shouldn't and doesn't change anything.

Comment: nice addictive game - although after playing it for 98.1 seconds and coming back to stackoverflow i feel like my eyes have been blinded, that hurt...

Comment: Have you tried the firebug profiler in FF4 ?

Comment: @Schnalle firefox bug: `ctx.arc(75,75,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);` see line 270. .arc requires 6 arguments not 5.

Comment: @shadi: thanks! and yes, the color scheme is madness. i'll change it!  
@raynos: yes, i tried, but i wasn't able to find anything. thanks for the ctx.arc bug (though it works well without that).  
@fazo: then play it in chrome and you'll get over 100fps :)

Comment: actually the arc's 6th argument is optional and defaults to false (clockwise) - check the reference http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html

Comment: and it seems to work perfectly fine in FF 4.0b10 on my OSX (68fps on an old macbook pro)

Comment: @tom tu: interesting. now i just have to find someone with an old macbook pro so i can test it there :)

Comment: @Schnalle I've tested it in Firefox 3.6.13 on my iMac as well - 72fps on the first and 64-68 fps on further plays (core i5 imac) - works perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it's not working on FF 3.6.13 OS X.

While I was developing [Snake JS](http://github.com/betamos/Snake-JS) I found a difference in `setInterval` behavior. You should really have a look at this:

```
var timer = setInterval(fn, 500)
// ...
timer = setInterval(fn, 500)
// Since I didn't use clearInterval() I now have two timers running in FF.
```

I see you're not using `setInterval`, but maybe it's something similar with `setTimeout`?

Comment: to be honest, i didn't even try any browsers except chrome and ff4 yet. i saw someone playing on safari, and it worked. but ff3? i doubt it would ever run fast enough.

Comment: regarding multiple setTimeouts: i checked, and that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had major issues with some higher end canvas applications I've built and used when having to deal with firefox 6 and under. There are many issues that involve performance and just poorly or completely unsupported canvas capabilities in firefox. They did make a huge update in firefox 7 that improves many of the issues that you are probably noticing. It's kind of annoying, i need to support down to ff4 on a huge facebook canvas-based app that doesnt quite work that great in 6 and lower. I've done so many things to try and hack around the performance related issues and it's really difficult to find solutions for most things.

Comment: i'm not sure this was a canvas problem at all - probably a timer issue or gc problem - it's just that you only notice it with canvas animations that are supposed to be smooth. the rendering was fast, just the timer event fired waaaay too late. i should port it to requestAnimationFrame and see if that makes any difference, but it was a weekend project so it doesn't really matter right now.

Comment: Well either way, there definitely are issues with performance in firefox 6 and below. I can confirm that 110%.